# TypeError: iText() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'text' and 'data_frame'

Tags: python, pytest

this is my function.py

```
def iText(text, data_frame):
    url = requests.get("http://nlp.cs.aueb.gr/software_and_datasets/lingspam_public.tar.gz")
    text = url\[-1\].strip()      
    label = url\[-1\].strip()                   
    data_frame = pd.DataFrame(text, label)

    return text, data_frame
```

this my file test_fc.py

```
def test_coba():
    text = iText
    data_frame = iText
    assert text, data_frame
```

It runs but I'm not sure if it is right. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not right.  Your `iText` function doesn't have any inputs, so it shouldn't have any parameters.  Next, in your test function, you need to CALL `iText` and check what it returns:

```
def iText():
    url = requests.get("http://nlp.cs.aueb.gr/software_and_datasets/lingspam_public.tar.gz")
    text = url[-1].strip()      
    label = url[-1].strip()                   
    data_frame = pd.DataFrame(text, label)
    return text, data_frame

def test_coba():
    text, data_frame = iText()
    assert text, data_frame
```

However, if you're fetching a tarball, what do you think `url[-1].strip()` is going to do?

Comment: so, what should i do?   so just print like print(itext) on my test_coba?

Comment: Do you even know what you are fetching here?  It's an 11 megabyte gzip library.  What are you expecting to do with this?

Comment: i just wanna call the function from iText  to test_coba how I can do Mr. Roberts?

Comment: That's exactly what I have provided here.